# Notepad++ change style console

Tags: console, notepad++

How I can change style of console in notepad++? 
When I'm changing style in Settings → Style Configurator then Console dialog not changing. And I would be like
[here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-g6DvomiQhTI/UB44ZlY4UeI/AAAAAAAABEQ/7dIcHRpnIO4/s1600/10.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found solved.

If somebody looking for also this. This can change this in NppExec -> Advanced Options. Section [Console] options TextColorNormal and BackgroungColor.